# How do I create a list where each element has a name and several lists within the element?

Tags: java, list, nested-lists

I am trying to write a program in java that allows me to add courses to a list and within each course element, I can add a list of assignments such as homework, exams, etc. Within each assignment I will have "homework 1" grade, "homework 2" grade, etc... How do I implement this in java?

Its hard to explain what I wish to do so hopefully this will help:

```
Courses:
  History:
    Homework:
      Homework 1 89
      Homework 2 98
    Exams:
      Exam 1 90
      Exam 2 87
  Science:
    Homework:
      Homework 1 88
    Exams:
      Exam 1 86
```

So, a list of courses, with each course having a list of assignments, with each assignment having a list of grades.

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: Are you specifically learning about nested lists? Because possibly what you need are classes, for example a `Course` class, a `Homework` class, an `Exam` class

Comment: What about this specifically confuses you? Where's your attempt?

Comment: I don't have an attempt. I have been messing around with the List class in java but I cannot think of how to even attempt what I am wanting to do. I don't know if I am looking at nested lists or classes. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What you want is a `Course` class and a `Map<String, Course>` to look them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good point to start learning about Classes.

You can do something like

```
public class Course {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> homeWorkScores;
    public Course(String courseName){
        this.name = courseName;
        homeWorkScores = new ArrayList<Integers>();
    }

    public String getCourseName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean addHomeWorkScore(Integer score){
        return homeWorkScores.add(score);
    }
}
```

Then instantiate it like :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
}
```

Comment: Since looking up courses by name seems a likely use case, a `Map<String, Course>` may be preferable to a `List<Course>`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I would leave the data structure part to OP. Purpose of this is to demonstrate how we can create a List of a List.

Comment: The question *is* "How do I create a list where each element has a name..."

Comment: Again I think I have depicted what the OP needs. Course -> has a name in the list of courses ! Feel free to edit or write your own solution.

Comment: Thank you StackFlowed for your answer. I threw around the idea of creating a class and making a list of those class objects but when I tried a basic version of it, it wouldn't work. Your answer has re-affirmed my thoughts of creating my own course class. Now I just need to try again.